# how to use charStrip nsis

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm not so sure if I understood how to use charStrip, so I'd created the script below and isn't showing anything on $current_compare, please help 
I'd tried to call this function but isn't working.

```
Exch $R0 #char <br/>
Exch <br/>
Exch $R1 #in string <br/>
Push $R2 <br/>
Push $R3 <br/>
Push $R4 <br/>
 StrCpy $R2 -1 <br/>
 IntOp $R2 $R2 + 1 <br/>
 StrCpy $R3 $R1 1 $R2 <br/>
 StrCmp $R3 "" +8 <br/>
 StrCmp $R3 $R0 0 -3 <br/>
  StrCpy $R3 $R1 $R2 <br/>
  IntOp $R2 $R2 + 1 <br/>
  StrCpy $R4 $R1 "" $R2 <br/>
  StrCpy $R1 $R3$R4 <br/>
  IntOp $R2 $R2 - 2 <br/>
  Goto -9 <br/>
  StrCpy $R0 $R1 <br/>
Pop $R4 <br/>
Pop $R3 <br/>
Pop $R2 <br/>
Pop $R1 <br/>
Exch $R0 <br/>
FunctionEnd <br/>

OutFile test.exe <br/>

Var /GLOBAL CURRENT_COMPARE <br/>
Section 1 <br/>
  !macro CharStrip Char InStr OutVar <br/>
  Push '.' <br/>
  Push 'v8.11.3' <br/>
  Call CharStrip <br/>
 Pop '$CURRENT_COMPARE' <br/>
!macroend <br/>
MessageBox MB_OK $CURRENT_COMPARE <br/>
 SectionEnd <br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you modified [this code](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/CharStrip_&_StrStrip:_Remove_character_or_string_from_another_string) from the Wiki.

In your example you are not inserting the macro so the CharStrip function is never called. You are not supposed to modify the macro, you just pass it the correct parameters:

```
Function CharStrip
Exch $R0 #char
Exch
Exch $R1 #in string
Push $R2
Push $R3
Push $R4
 StrCpy $R2 -1
 IntOp $R2 $R2 + 1
 StrCpy $R3 $R1 1 $R2
 StrCmp $R3 "" +8
 StrCmp $R3 $R0 0 -3
  StrCpy $R3 $R1 $R2
  IntOp $R2 $R2 + 1
  StrCpy $R4 $R1 "" $R2
  StrCpy $R1 $R3$R4
  IntOp $R2 $R2 - 2
  Goto -9
  StrCpy $R0 $R1
Pop $R4
Pop $R3
Pop $R2
Pop $R1
Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
!macro CharStrip Char InStr OutVar
 Push '${InStr}'
 Push '${Char}'
  Call CharStrip
 Pop '${OutVar}'
!macroend
!define CharStrip '!insertmacro CharStrip'

Var /GLOBAL CURRENT_COMPARE

Section 1
${CharStrip} '.' 'v8.11.3' $CURRENT_COMPARE
MessageBox mb_OK $CURRENT_COMPARE
SectionEnd
```